# Don't show closed questions on front page

Tags: discussion, software-engineering-se

This is what I see when I go to [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) (yellow highlight by me).
All questions except **two** on the first "page" are closed. I can of course scroll down to see lots of questions that aren't closed but I think it gives a bad first impression.

[image: Programmers Front Page]

Comment: -1 Terrible idea. Most people won't even open closed questions as it is. If they were moved off the front page, the chances of a closed question getting reopened would be practically zero.

Comment: That's at least partially my bad. I got a touch carried away with the nightly retagging. Sorry about that.

Comment: I [complained about a similar issue](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103215/) but was down-voted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like this was mostly caused by [Anna Lear ♦](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/226/anna-lear) cleaning up the tags (e.g. removing [sparetime](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sparetime) and [self-teaching](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/self-teaching)) on some old questions, which automatically get bumped to the front page. I agree that it gives a bad first impression, but bumping edited questions to the front page is definitely by design.

Comment: It does seem a bit redundant, though.

Answer (score 7):

Closing isn't a dead end. Closed questions can be reopened. Therefore there shouldn't be a blanket ban on closed questions appearing on the home page.

If you think there's a salvageable post in there edit it and vote to reopen (if you have the necessary reputation). If you don't have the reputation, suggest an edit and flag the post for  moderator to review.

As to the specifics of this case, edit floods are to be avoided but are sometimes unavoidable. The normal activity on a reasonably active site will soon replace these questions with (hopefully) better ones. On Stack Overflow you wouldn't notice an edit flood as the home page changes so often.

There have been calls for mods to be able to edit posts with out bumping them (this is what CHAOS could do briefly) but these have always been rejected. The only thing we can do within the current rules is to try and space out edits to minimise their effect. However, if (as in this case) there's a tag that needs replacing by other, more appropriate flags there's not a lot else we can do.

Comment: **I** know how it works. I'm thinking of new users. And I *still* don't think they should show up on the front page. The front page should be where we should put questions we are proud of.

Comment: @Nifle - I updated the answer.

Comment: Edited my comment while you wrote your comment.