# I made us some Trogdor graphics!

Tags: discussion, fun

We seem to have a tradition of using the [Homestar Runner](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homestar_Runner) character 'Trogdor the Burninator' to request tag deletion.

[image: Screenshot of Trogdor, the burninator]

I thought we could use crisper images, so I made my own. >:)

Comment: Who wants to be the first to use these? :)

Comment: A Trogdor bat signal?

Comment: There will have to be a tag 'trogdord" or "burninated" for those that fall to Him

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes.

Comment: Nice! Only devs can completely burninate tags, but the burninator signal will be a nice addition to burnination-request posts. Now that Jeff's leaving, I'm not sure who will be the new trogdor... we'll see!

Comment: Related: [The true meaning of burninate](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/the-true-meaning-of-burninate)

Comment: +2 just because I can.

Comment: Shouldn't those images be posted as an answer, instead?

Comment: @Chris Why yes, they should... which also lets us up-vote multiple times! That said, I couldn't help thinking of Alex Trebek when I read your comment...

Comment: @Chris Fixed it!

Comment: @iglvzx http://meta.askubuntu.com/posts/2489/revisions :D

Comment: @Sathya Use the new graphic. I fixed a few minor problems with the coloring. :P

Comment: @iglvzx congrats :P http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/2502/1182

Comment: Rep cap two days in a row, what did I say? ;)

Comment: rofl, rofl, rofl.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

### Request:

[image: request]

[image: request-alt]

### Burninated:

[image: burninated]

### BONUS:

The above were made using a Trogdor reference from an unknown person on the internet, which has some inaccuracies. I went to the source (Strongbad), and retraced Trogdor. This is the real Trogdor, in color, in higher definition:

[image: Trogdor the Burninator]

Comment: my name is Jeff Atwood and I approve of this message.

Comment: So happy! @Jeff I hope you still stick around for some good ol' burninating from time to time.

Comment: @Jeff UPDATED! NOW IN COLOR!

Comment: *and transparent backgrounds.

Comment: @troggy will be happy :P

Comment: @YiJiang'sProble_ You do not need to change the kerning. If you watch the cartoon, the text is actually spaced like that. :)

Comment: @iglvzx Oh, okay, but it's just that the... [bad kerning](http://xkcd.com/1015/)... must... resist... argh! \*stabs eye with pen*

Comment: Those Vs are so consummate! *tears up*

Comment: Tshirt of Burninator Signal plz.

Comment: Request: Trogdor animated GIF

Answer (score 66):

This inspired me, so I made some ASCII:

```
                                     {
                                   ( ) }
                  "--____            ))
           "      ) -_(        \/   (
      ___-´ \     | _(        0  o
        )_-  `_   / (__-+`''-------=.         _____
          )_-  \,/-'       ,--______:     .--´   /      ___
    __.-----_)_-\        <(    V v v  ---'     _'=-----'/
  .´    --   /             `-----___. -__     {__ `----'_
  |   ,    .´          ___----------'    `-_     '-----___----'
 (    /'--'|         --                     `--.__---''
 (    /   '         /
  |  /_   |        |
  (  _-)  \        \
   '-_)    '.       \_
              -_       \_
                `--_     `-__
                    `-__     `-_
                /\      `-_     \
        --.__A-/__\       _)     |          B  U  R  N  I  N  A  T  E  D  !
             `--   `-/\_-'     _/
                `-__      ___-'
                  | `-.--'
                  |    \
                  L__   \_.-
```

Comment: Well done. *pun-intended*

Comment: I entered 10 puns into a contest to see which would win. No pun in ten did.

Answer (score 17):

@iglvzx's Trogdor is great, sure, but I always imagined trogdor as having a red skin (yes, I have played peasant's quest, but my artistic style is not to be questioned!).

I have also taken on the daunting task of converting our good friend Mr. Troggie into a vector format (SVG), which you can download [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108400557/TROGDOR.svg):
[imageDescr http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108400557/TROGDOR.svg](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/108400557/TROGDOR.svg)

And for those of you who don't have a browser capable of SVG, then here's a PNG render:

[image: Trogdor PNG]

Do what you will with this file, and hopefully trogdor can burninate more!

Comment: Inkscape? Pfft, I hand craft my SVGs.

Comment: @bjb568 Honestly I would have, I'm just a terrible artist. Here's the best I could do with about 10 minutes in pixelmator: http://imgur.com/lBQhmB2, just to give you an idea of how horrible I truly am.

Comment: Oh, god. Well +1 for macs. Apple FTW!

Comment: Your link is dead! :(

Comment: Do you still have a copy?

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Not that I know of, its probably on one of my old hard drives... If I ever dig it up I'll ping you here.