# Suspected pattern of replies

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Possible sockpuppet - What’s the procedure?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127467/possible-sockpuppet-whats-the-procedure)

I've noticed that a user seems to exhibit the following pattern.

1. When he gets downvoted, in a short while he gets upvoted (e.g. it says +3/-3).
2. There seems to be a set of users that always mark his reply as answer (his reply is sometimes a bit off, he'd not incompetens but not all his replies are top noch).
3. The said set exhibits a bit of suspicious behavior as well, but not that much.
4. Replies to other users seem not to be as successful as the said set.
5. He's over 10k in less than 18 months.

Should I report it? To whom/how?

I don't want him to get into trouble in case he's honest but I don't want a cheater to be at large.

Comment: See [Possible sockpuppet - What's the procedure?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127467) flag and leave it to the moderators.

Comment: Over 10k in 18 months is not that much of a surprise. If one has time, it is attainable 2-3 months.

Comment: @nhahtdh I'm **not** saying he's a cheat. I can imagine it's possible. I'm just asking what todo since, although possible, it's a bit unlikley. Also, I had a full list of hmmm's, not only his score.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link. I didn't know there was a name for such thing. It's good that there's a thread for that kind of problems but it's also a bit worrying that there is such a thread...

Comment: Go ahead and flag one of the user's posts for moderator attention and we'll look into it...

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Done. Now I have guilty conscience - what if he gets banned BUT was innocent? Can I un-flag someone?

Comment: You cannot unflag somebody. What you *can* do, however, is trust that we'll make the right judgement on this matter :)

Comment: @AndreasJohansson You can be pretty confident that a suspension requires solid evidence. The moderators just need to be told where to start the investigation.