# Set [Troubleshooting] to Burninate

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [troubleshooting](/questions/tagged/troubleshooting) tag (385 questions) appears to be useless. It does not add anything to the site, and I highly doubt it is used to locate questions.

Should this tag be [burninated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012)?

```
                                     {
                                   ( ) }
                  "--____            ))
           "      ) -_(        \/   (
      ___-´ \     | _(        0  o
        )_-  `_   / (__-+`''-------=.         _____
          )_-  \,/-'       ,--______:     .--´   /      ___
    __.-----_)_-\        <(    V v v  ---'     _'=-----'/
  .´    --   /             `-----___. -__     {__ `----'_
  |   ,    .´          ___----------'    `-_     '-----___----'
 (    /'--'|         --                     `--.__---''
 (    /   '         /
  |  /_   |        |
  (  _-)  \        \
   '-_)    '.       \_
              -_       \_
                `--_     `-__
                    `-__     `-_
                /\      `-_     \
        --.__A-/__\       _)     |          B  U  R  N  I  N  A  T  E  !
             `--   `-/\_-'     _/
                `-__      ___-'
                  | `-.--'
                  |    \
                  L__   \_.-
```

<sub>**Trogdor ASCII [source.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121592/166938)**</sub>

Comment: You are missing a semicolon... But I'm not gonna say where...

Comment: Ugh, you made me check if Jeff had edited to add a semicolon...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *Ah, aaaaaaaaaaaaaaah, Ah! Ah, aaaaaaaaaaah, Ah!
>
>   We come from the land of the ice and snow,
>
>   From the midnight sun where the hot springs blow.
>
>   The hammer of the gods will drive our ships to new lands,
>
>   To fight the horde, singing and crying: Valhalla, I am coming!*

[image]