# No more holidays

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Can we burn the [holidays](/questions/tagged/holidays) tag? It's clearly a [meta-tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) with no value.
*(37 questions all of which have other, more relevant, tags)*

Comment: But how else will I ask questions about santa claus?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, well we can pick either `dec-25` or `oct-31`...

Comment: You can still ask questions about santa claus, you just can't tag them as [holidays]

Comment: @doubleDown In 'murica, we do what we want!

Comment: Just a comment: you've asked for it to be burninated, but you haven't stated *why* it's a bad tag. Most would agree (even at a quick glance) that it's not a particularly useful tag but it's still a good idea to outline why.

Comment: @slugster good point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I cleaned up most of these questions, barring a few that I felt were *really* bad and deserved closure & deletion. The tag itself will disappear in 24 hours after the remaining questions are gone.

Most of the questions there were perfectly good questions (although most focusing on having a database of holday dates), so I didn't feel it was necessary to close most of them. Feel free to peruse my [editing history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/427309/richard-j-ross-iii?tab=activity&sort=revisions) if you disagree.

[image]

Comment: glad you got in the festive spirit! Thanks for doing that. I voted to close/delete the remaining 6 (so hopefully they won't last long).

Comment: You forgot the picture!

Comment: @Undo I am disappointed that you didn't use [my picture](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/148353/151015)

Comment: I'll try to remember in the future :)