# Can trusted users delete accepted answers with a negative score?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, deleted-answers, trusted-user

A user recently pointed out a few questions with incredibly bad accepted answers on our site's meta asking us if there is anything we can do about it. I'm aware that users can delete answers if they have a sufficiently high reputation but I don't know if this privilege applies to accepted answers as well.

Comment: Point us at one and we can try it...

Comment: @dmckee: Took a while, but I finally found one here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45543/the-word-programmatically/45553#45553

Comment: D'oh! I'm about 540 points short of being trusted on meta...

Comment: I believe you can vote to delete someone else's answer regardless of its accepted state, but not your own.

Comment: @dmckee Well, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808327/how-to-read-modelstate-errors-when-returned-by-json/2808460#2808460)'s one on SO.

Comment: Let's see...it accepted my vote.

Comment: Here's a bunch more for you guys to try out:  http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/60842

Comment: [Here's one that is a definite "not an answer" and that the author requests removal of](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4155819/73226). I've voted to delete so two more votes?

Comment: This is probably the most "famous" accepted answer I can think of that should be put out of its misery this way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209170/how-much-does-it-cost-to-develop-an-iphone-application

Comment: Interesting, supposedly this _isn't_ supposed to be possible: [20k users can vote to delete negatively voted accepted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83356). I don't see any reason for it not to be, however.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer to this question is "yes".

The [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4155748/73226) used to have an accepted answer consisting entirely of the text

> INCORRECT ANSWER REMOVED (if the OP unaccepts it, I'll delete it)

but this has now been successfully deleted by three 20K+ users.

Comment: So did that automatically "unaccept" it, or does it show as a deleted answer with a checkmark?

Comment: It shows as a deleted answer with a checkmark. Does that mean the OP can't accept the other answer now if they were to get the urge?

Comment: The question does not have accepted answer now, you can see this [here](http://i.imgur.com/6L0CK.png) - so the OP should be able to accept other answer. But as he didn't bother for year and half I doubt he will do such effort now.

Comment: @MartinSmith You can accept other answers by just clicking their checkmark, which automatically removes it from the answer that had it, so I assume it'd work even if that answer is deleted.

Comment: Also, fun fact: You can't directly accept or unaccept a deleted answer because those count as a vote.